# How do i get all the class names that are present in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, class

I am working on a code that displays all the public properties of a class present in a javascript file.Currently, the user types the name of the class in a text box. Instead of the user typing the name of the class in a text box, i want to display the list of classes present in the javascript file and allow the user to choose which ever class he wishes.

A solution in c# was to load the dll and the get all the types in the assembly using Assembly.getTypes() function. But am looking to find all the class types in a javascript file.

Is this possible? Will it be a problem as javascript is an interpreted language?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you call a "class"?

Comment: Since a class in javascript is essentially a function I think functions and classes will be very difficult to tell apart.

Comment: A class is any type that i can create an object of. For example      function myclass() { this.aProp=0; this.bprop=0;}       i can create an onject of myClass using the following statement: var myObj= new myClass();

Answer (score 0):

Classes are nothing but functions in JavaScript, and functions are just variables. If you define a class like this:

```
function myClass() {
    // ...
}
```

..it becomes a global variable (window.myClass), so you might take a look at the window object to find all defined (global) classes.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the following 
 for(var cl in window)
 {
  document.writeln("<p>"+cl+"</p>")
 }                                                         It displayed all the predefined properties and funtioncs like onbeforeunload,status,document,onmessage,onblur,onunload,event,self,clientInformation etc. If i mention the function directly say "windows.myClass" the entire function code is displayed. So i do not understand why it didn come with the above code.                                                                Is there something i am missing?

Comment: `for (var cl in window)` gives you the indices, not the values - `window[cl]` would be what you need. But as you already noticed, the window object has many predefined properties you will need to sort out in some way.

Comment: Thanks. The value of window[myclass] is displayed as 'undefined'. When i changed the above code to for (var cl in window){ document.writeln("<p>"+window[cl]+"</p>"); , the name of the functions dont get displayed. Any suggestions?

Comment: cl is the name, window[cl] the function itself. `window[myclass]` can't work, because js looks for a variable named "myclass", correct would be: `window['myclass']`

Comment: Thanks. window['myClass'] is showing the entire function code. I am unable to get only the function name. And another thing, the for loop's output does not display the functions defined by me.